# What is the default layout for SWT widgets?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to know what is the default layout for SWT widgets?

For example: If we put Composite on top of a Shell, what will be the default layout assigned for that composite in SWT?

Answer (score 1):

For a composite control you create yourself there is no default layout and children will not be visible (unless you set their bounds which is not  recommended).

In Eclipse plugins most controls that you are given by Eclipse or JFace have a layout set, most often `FillLayout`.

You can always call the `getLayout()` method of any composite control to find out the layout it is using.